In Vulkan - OpenGL interop, what tiling would an image need?
I have set up a program that does Vulkan - OpenGL interop. I heavily borrowed from the Vulkan Sample.
The idea is: Vulkan creates an image and semaphores. OpenGL will render to the image and Vulkan will present this image to the window (OpenGL renders offscreen).
In my case, I have Qt for the Vulkan rendering and GLFW for the OpenGL rendering, and due to Qt constraints I don't immediately present the image. Nevertheless, the interop is pretty much the same.
Now on my Vulkan side, I had a bug where the outputs of OpenGL wouldn't be visible. I used it as a sampler in my image, but it would always be black. OpenGL would render a blue-ish image and I could verify that in RenderDoc.
After searching for the issue for about a week, I found that once I turned the shared image to use tiling VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL (rather than VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR, which I assumed I needed), I can finally see the output of OpenGL (also verified in RenderDoc). I was so annoyed, I tried to break the Vulkan Sample with the same idea: set the shared image to be TILING_LINEAR - but here it still works.
Now I am a bit at a loss - what should be the correct image tiling? Is it reasonable, that due to this setting I would get a black input image on the Vulkan side?
My thoughts for why TILING_LINEAR makes more sense is that Vulkan (or the driver) does optimal however it wants to, it's opaque to the user. In this case, since OpenGL only imports the setting and has no idea about tiling (afaik), I would consider it a "user", meaning it has no idea about what "optimal" would be.
Is this an incorrect assumption?

Since I just learned that linear tiling works only with a few specific formats: In my program it was VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_SFLOAT / GL_RGBA32F. In the sample it is VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM / GL_RGBA8. So I changed my program to use that as well, and it still doesn't work with linear tiling.
